# Javascript code not working using template inheritence in Django template

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I am having trouble in executing Javascript code in a Django project.

The following is working fine - i.e. without using template inheritence

html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

    <head>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="{% static 'ads/test.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title> Test </title>

    </head>

    <body>

      <form action="{% url 'test' %}" method="post" id="my_form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
      </form>

    </body>
   </html>
```

test.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#my_form").submit(function(){

alert('submitted');

});
});
```

Since the above external Javascript file test.js has executed successfully, I assume the settings of static url, static dirs, etc. are correct. Also, since jquery has worked, I assume the order of jquery first, then js code is also correct.

The problem comes when I use template inheritence.

base html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

{% block scripts %}
{% endblock %}

<title> {% block title %}{% endblock %} </title>

</head>

<body>

{% block body %}
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

inherited template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block scripts %}
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'ads/test2.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}
 Test
{% endblock %} 

{% block body %}
<form action="{% url 'test' %}" method="post" id="my_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

However the above is not working i.e. nothing is happening on submitting the button. The only change is the template inheritence - without it, the js code is working but by including it something is going wrong.

In Chrome - Inspect - Network, the test.js file is not being loaded - but the bootstrap, popper, jquery js files are seen to be loaded. Chrome console shows no error

Is there something wrong in the way I am extending the base template or inheriting it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should load static at the top after extending, but not inside block. So, try something like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
// My change
{% load static %}

{% block scripts %}
// Changed from
<script src="{% static 'ads/test2.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}Test{% endblock %} 

{% block body %}
<form action="{% url 'test' %}" method="post" id="my_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: made the suggested change, still the js file is not getting loaded.

Answer (score 0):

For me works if you add {% load static %} on the base file as well. Here is your base:

```html
{% load static %} <!--Don't forget this-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

{% block scripts %}
{% endblock %}

<title> {% block title %}{% endblock %} </title>

</head>

<body>

{% block body %}
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the inherited

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block scripts %}
// Changed from
<script src="{% static 'ads/test2.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}Test{% endblock %} 

{% block body %}
<form action="{% url 'test' %}" method="post" id="my_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```